# Is there a way for retrieving an external DOM in PHP (with loadHTMLfile) including some headers in the html call?

Tags: php, dom, header

I'm trying to get some DOM from external URLs while passing some headers, so the received DOM must be different depending on them.

For instance, if I have a mobile device header, the received DOM should be completely different than from a PC header.

At the moment I haven't found the way to do this, as I'm always receiving the same DOM (with my default headers).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a so called *stream context* for the load operation. Check this example, which is derived from the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-set-streams-context.php)

```
// Specify headers
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'user_agent' => 'PHP libxml agent',
    )
);

// Create and assign a stream context    
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
libxml_set_streams_context($context);

// request the HTML file through HTTP
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile('http://www.example.com/file.html');
```

You can follow theses articles in the PHP manual:

- [DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php)
- [stream_context_create()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.stream-context-create.php)
- [libxml_set_streams_context()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-set-streams-context.php)
- [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php)
- [HTTP context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)

Comment: Thank you, hek2mlg, but I have a problem trying to get your code to work properly. When I load the saveHTML from $doc, I see that the received DOM ignores my new headers. Is it because we didn't use the created $context in our $doc?  I hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: I echo the HTML received from the call with "echo $doc->saveHTML();"

Comment: No, `libxml_set_streams_context()` will do. There is no option to set this using the `DOMDocument` class. I assume you set the wrong header value, missed some headers or have a syntax error in header syntax.